# не сохраняет SharedPreferences в fragment

Tags: java, android

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем моя ошибка. В Activity работает но в fragment не сохраняет в SharedPreferences

```
public class ftab3 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{


    private SharedPreferences sharedPrefskyr;
    private TextView Startink2;
    private TextView Period21;
    private TextView Period11;
    private TextView Period31;
    private TextView Vilup1;

    public static final String myPrefskyr = "myprefskyr";
    public static final String namevilupkyr = "nameKey1kyr";
    public static final String namestartkyr = "nameKey2kyr";
    public static final String nameper1kyr = "nameKey3kur";
    public static final String nameper2kyr = "nameKey4kyr";
    public static final String nameper3kyr = "nameKey5kyr";


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ftab3, container, false);

        Startink2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.data1per1);
        long date1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd MMM yyyy");
        String dateV = sdf.format(date1);
        Startink2.setText(dateV);

        Period11 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.data2per1);
        long date2 = System.currentTimeMillis()+ (8 * 86400000);
        SimpleDateFormat p = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd MMM yyyy");
        String dateX = p.format(date2);
        Period11.setText(dateX);

        Period21 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.data3per1);
        long date3 = System.currentTimeMillis()+ (15 * 86400000);
        SimpleDateFormat N = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm");
        String dateY = N.format(date3);
        Period21.setText(dateY);

        Period31 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.data4per1);
        long date4 = System.currentTimeMillis()+ (19 * 86400000);
        SimpleDateFormat Nc = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm");
        String dateJ = Nc.format(date4);
        Period31.setText(dateJ);

        Vilup1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.data5per1);
        long date6 = System.currentTimeMillis()+ (21 * 86400000);
        SimpleDateFormat rdf = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm");
        String dateS = rdf.format(date6);
        Vilup1.setText(dateS);

    
        sharedPrefskyr = getActivity ().getSharedPreferences(myPrefskyr, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (sharedPrefskyr.contains(namevilupkyr)) {
                     Vilup1.setText(dateS);
        }
        if (sharedPrefskyr.contains(namestartkyr)) {
            Startink2.setText(dateV);
        }
        if (sharedPrefskyr.contains(nameper1kyr)) {
            Period11.setText(dateX);
        }
        if (sharedPrefskyr.contains(nameper2kyr)) {
            Period21.setText(dateY);
        }
        if (sharedPrefskyr.contains(nameper3kyr)) {
            Period31.setText(dateJ);
        }
        return view;
    }

     public void saveText() {
   
        String editTextValue = Vilup1.getText().toString();
        String editTextValue2 = Startink2.getText().toString();
        String editTextValue3 = Period11.getText().toString();
        String editTextValue4 = Period21.getText().toString();
        String editTextValue5 = Period31.getText().toString();

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefskyr.edit();
        editor.putString(namevilupkyr, editTextValue);
        editor.putString(namestartkyr, editTextValue2);
        editor.putString(nameper1kyr, editTextValue3);
        editor.putString(nameper2kyr, editTextValue4);
        editor.putString(nameper3kyr, editTextValue5);

        editor.apply();
    }

      public void getText() {
        sharedPrefskyr = getActivity ().getSharedPreferences(myPrefskyr, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (sharedPrefskyr.contains(namevilupkyr)) {
            Vilup1.setText(sharedPrefskyr.getString(namevilupkyr, ""));
        }
        if (sharedPrefskyr.contains(namestartkyr)) {
            Startink2.setText(sharedPrefskyr.getString(namestartkyr, ""));
        }
        if (sharedPrefskyr.contains(nameper1kyr)) {
            Period11.setText(sharedPrefskyr.getString(nameper1kyr, ""));
        }
        if (sharedPrefskyr.contains(nameper2kyr)) {
            Period21.setText(sharedPrefskyr.getString(nameper2kyr, ""));
        }
        if (sharedPrefskyr.contains(nameper3kyr)) {
            Period31.setText(sharedPrefskyr.getString(nameper3kyr, ""));
        }

    }

       @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.saveBtn22:
                saveText();
             Toast.makeText(getActivity (), "Сохранить", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;


            case R.id.getBtn22:
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity (), "Получить", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                getText();
                break;


        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Может кому-то покажется смешным моя реализация, но работу с SharedPreferences я у себя реализовал так:

1. static int, static boolean и т.д.
2. при создании Activity делаю чтение настроек:

   ```
        mSettings = context.getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
   ```
3. читаю настройки

   ```
    _koef_alt_2_main = _read_new_sett_boolean("_koef_alt_2_main", false);
    _volume_main_tank = _read_new_sett_float("_volume_main_tank", 55);
    _type_fuel_alt = _read_new_sett_string("_type_fuel_alt", "Пропан");
   ```
4. Делаю дополнительные функции чтения / записи данных

   ```
    public static String _read_new_sett_string(String _label, String _def) {
    if (mSettings.contains(_label)) {
        return mSettings.getString(_label, _def);
    } else {
        return _def;
    }
    }

    public static float _read_new_sett_float(String _label, float _def) {
    if (mSettings.contains(_label)) {
        return mSettings.getFloat(_label, _def);
    } else {
        return _def;
    }
    }
    public static Boolean _read_new_sett_boolean(String _label, Boolean _def) {
    if (mSettings.contains(_label)) {
        return mSettings.getBoolean(_label, _def);
    } else {
        return _def;
    }
    }

    public static void _save_new_sett_string(String _label, String _input) {
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSettings.edit();
       editor.putString(_label, _input);
       editor.apply();
    }
    public static void _save_new_sett_float(String _label, float _input) {
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSettings.edit();
       editor.putFloat(_label, _input);
       editor.apply();
    }
    public static void _save_new_sett_boolean(String _label, Boolean _input) {
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSettings.edit();
       editor.putBoolean(_label, _input);
       editor.apply();
    }
   ```
5. В программе работаю с переменными, в любом месте. Если мне нужно изменить переменную и записать её, вызываю функцию

   ```
   _save_new_sett_boolean("restart_on_lost", _restart_on_lost.isChecked());
   ```

Все примеры это вырезки из кода, между собой не связаны переменными

Comment: Как эти ответы связанны с fragment - я так понимаю в классе frgmenta getSharedPreferences не работает на прямую?

Comment: Не могу сказать точно, но мой код работает как в activity,  так и фрагментах и отдельных сервисах

Answer (score -1):

Создай отдельный Java Class и пропиши анологично этого:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;

    public class SharedPref {
        public static final String APP_PREFERENCES = "mysettings";
        public static final String NIGHT_MODE = "NightMode";
        public static final String APP_PREFERENCES_COUNTER = "counter";
        SharedPreferences mySharedPref ;
        public SharedPref(Context context) {
            mySharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
        }
        // this method will save the nightMode State : True or False
        public void setNightModeState(Boolean value) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPref.edit();
            editor.putBoolean(NIGHT_MODE,value);
            editor.apply();
        }
        // this method will load the Night Mode State
        public Boolean loadNightModeState (){
            return mySharedPref.getBoolean(NIGHT_MODE,false);
        }
    
        public void setLanguageState(String lang){
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString("My_Lang", lang);
            editor.apply();
        }
        // Вызов метода с помошью SharedPreferences
    
        public String getString(String my_lang, String s) {
            return mySharedPref.getString("My_Lang","");
        }
    }
```

И потом начинай присваевать куда тебе надо.